# How to insert date or other `Template expansion` in org capture when no "*" prompt in file?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I want to insert the date in the capture template, but I do not want to add a "*" at the beginning of the file.
How do I achieve this?

An example as follows, `C-c c p p` work fine, but `C-c c p l` display "Template is not a valid Org entry or tree".

```lisp
(global-set-key "\C-cc" 'org-capture)
(setq org-capture-templates   
      '(

    ("p" "programme")
    ("pl" "perl" entry
     (file (lambda ()  (let ((name (read-string "FileName: " "<perl> ")))
                 (expand-file-name (format "%s.org" name)
                           "~/syncthing/notes/perl"))))
     "Date：%U\nFrom: %?\n\n")
    ("pp" "python" entry
     (file (lambda ()  (let ((name (read-string "FileName: " "<python> ")))
                 (expand-file-name (format "%s.org" name)
                           "~/syncthing/notes/python"))))
     "* \nDate：%U\nFrom: %?\n\n")

    ))
```

Comment: Do you want `plain` instead of `entry`?

Comment: Yes, that is right, Thanks for your help.